# Getting all def functions of a file from a string containing the file name

Tags: python, string, list, function

I need to get all the def functions from .py files I have in a folder. 
I have this which gets the file names from the folder.

```
import Modules

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/Modules/"

modules=[]

os.chdir(path)
for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
    if file != "__init__.py":
        file = file.replace(".py", "")
        Module = "Modules." + file
```

This can get all the filenames fine and remove the .py from them the problem is that when I try and get the all the functions using this

```
for i in dir(Module):
        if i[0] != "_":
            print i
```

It prints out stuff like this

```
capitalize
center
count
decode
encode
```

which I think is functions for "strings" in general. I printed out modules and it return returned Modules.test, and by putting that into the function

```
 for i in dir(Modules.test):
        if i[0] != "_":
            print i
```

it did return "test"(which is the name of the def function I have in the file), I have tried converting the string into a raw string using [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65211-convert-a-string-into-a-raw-string/), but it that did not work. So I am just wondering how I would accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for fpath in glob.glob("*.py"):
    if not fpath.endswith("__init__.py"): #recall glob returns full path
        with open(fpath) as f:
             print os.path.basename(fpath)
             print "  "+"\n  ".join(re.findall("def (.*):",f.read()))
```

maybe .... I guess?

Comment: Great, works perfectly except would you know how to put these into a array so I could do something like Function[1]

Comment: So how would I call it so that I can get the first function it finds

Comment: Its fine I have just done Function_list = Functions.split()
                for word in Function_list:
                    Function_array += [word]